# Merge & Sum Rows in PowerBI Transform Data based on Multiple Criteria

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

So I have this table with locations named with IDs. Each ID can have data from multiple years, and multiple metric types. I want to merge and sum all the Water + Irrigation rows with matching ID/Year, and leave all the rest as-is. I want to do this in transform data, because I have other things I need to do with this table and data. Is this possible? I was thinking of maybe making a custom column that does a SUM IFS of some kind, and then visually filtering out all the irrigation rows? Please don't suggest a measure or something that isn't functional within Transform Data. I need to merge this table to another one once I complete this step.

Original Table:

| Row | ID | Year | Metric Type | January Use |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12 | 2022 | Water | **25** |
| 2 | 12 | 2022 | Irrigation | **55** |
| 3 | 12 | 2021 | Electricity | 28160 |
| 4 | 12 | 2022 | Electricity | 19760 |
| 5 | 423 | 2022 | Water | **46** |
| 6 | 423 | 2022 | Irrigation | **33** |
| 7 | 423 | 2022 | Natural Gas | 6340 |
| 8 | 89 | 2021 | Electricity | 21780 |
| 9 | 89 | 2022 | Natural Gas | 180 |
| 10 | 55 | 2022 | Water | 11 |

Desired Table:

| Row | ID | Year | Metric Type | January Use |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12 | 2022 | Water | **80** |
| 2 | 12 | 2021 | Electricity | 28160 |
| 3 | 12 | 2022 | Electricity | 19760 |
| 4 | 423 | 2022 | Water | **79** |
| 5 | 423 | 2022 | Natural Gas | 6340 |
| 6 | 89 | 2021 | Electricity | 21780 |
| 7 | 89 | 2022 | Natural Gas | 180 |
| 8 | 55 | 2022 | Water | 11 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just right click Metric Type and replace Irrigation with Water, then click select [ID, Year and Metric type] and group by, and take sum of January column

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(Source,"Irrigation","Water",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Metric Type"}),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Replaced Value", {"ID", "Year", "Metric Type"}, {{"January Use", each List.Sum([January Use]), type nullable number}})
in #"Grouped Rows"
```

Comment: Thanks! I have this tendency to make my problems way more complicated than they need to be.

Something I left out of my original solution was that I have multiple columns (one for each month), that I needed summed separately, but I actually just unpivoted them, then grouped by ID, Year, Month, and Metric and that seems to have done the trick!

Comment: Yep that's the way